# Getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when I try and require code from Node.js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

I am looking to start including my route files in my Node.js and express application. However, when I require the local route files into my server.js file, and try to run that on Nginx, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

The code that is giving me trouble is currently commented out. Any ideas on what might be causing this performance?

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

// const oidc = require('./okta');
// const searchRouter = require('./routes/search');
// const inputRouter = require('./routes/input');
// const dataRouter = require('./routes/view-all');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
  res.render(__dirname + '/views/optishop.ejs');
});

const listener = app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Edit: This is the file being required in the searchRouter declaration.
search.js

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

const oidc = require('../okta');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/search', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), async (req, res) => {
  await MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    { useUnifiedTopology: true },
    async (err, client) => {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      const db = client.db('test');

      const arr = req.body.item.trim().split(/; */gi);

      const user = req.session.passport.user.userinfo.sub;
      const cursor = await db
        .collection('test')
        .find({
          user
        })
        .toArray();

      const filteredCursor = cursor.filter(obj => {
        return arr.includes(obj.item);
      });

      res.render('index', {
        cursor: filteredCursor
      });
      // res.send(filteredCursor);
      client.close();
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: did you try to debug on the server rather than the client?

Comment: Would need to see those files. 502 means unreachable so something in those modules is breaking your app (obviously)

Comment: In the error log, it shows this error message: [error] 12747#12747: *41803 connect() failed (111: connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Comment: @CaptEmulation I have added one of the files to the question. This file is listed in a "routes" directory in the same directory as the server.js file.

Comment: I assume somewhere (in the borken version) you call `app.use(searchRouter)` ?

Comment: @CaptEmulation I had forgotten to add that, but I still get the error regardless.

Comment: Sorry I don't see anything obviously wrong. Making a DB connection on every request is unusual but I don't think the cause of your error.  Good luck!